# How to do create a form ui component select box with a source to fill select box

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I am trying to find out how I can create a select box in magento component ui form and point it to some where I can fill in the select list.

Something like this I thought would work but it does not

```
<field name="formats">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">formats</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\AttributeSet\Options</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">formats</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can add like this

```
<field name="formats">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\AttributeSet\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Formats</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">modulename</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">formats</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: Genius! May I ask where you got this information from for future reference?

Comment: You are at right place bro. Just keep searching :)

Comment: @Priyank where is the `modulename` from `<item name="source" />` defined ? I tried mine from module.xml, routes.xml but this doesn't work. I do receive this error message: http://prntscr.com/d9c73e

Comment: @Vasilii if your modulename is the name of your module you created . For eg if in for module Magento_Catalog the catalog is the modulename.

Comment: @Priyank it doesn't work in the way you described. I wonder if source make a reference to a module model or other .php file that contain select options.
P.S. I try this with `multiselect` type for `formElement`.

Comment: @VasiliiBurlacu are you facing any issue ?

Comment: @Priyank ! : Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/codility-magento-market-place/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 206 

I get this error when i past above code in ui_component file

Comment: It was long back then. Which Magento version are you using?

Answer (score 5):

This is an approach that is more common at least as of Magento 2.3:

```
<field name="image_overlay_art" sortOrder="40" formElement="select">
    <settings>
        <dataType>int</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Show Art on Image Overlay</label>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <select>
            <settings>
                <options class="\Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno"/>
            </settings>
        </select>
    </formElements>
</field>
```